# Convert Pdf to Image with ghost script MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, ghostscript

I want to convert Pdf file to image and I use ghostscript but it doesn't work properly.

```cs
var pp = new PDFConvert();
pp.OutputFormat = "jpeg"; //format
pp.JPEGQuality = 90; //100% quality
pp.ResolutionX = 120; //dpi
pp.ResolutionY = 120;
pp.FirstPageToConvert = 1; //pages you want
pp.LastPageToConvert = 1;                    
pp.Convert(Server.MapPath("~/Pdf Files/20.pdf"), Server.MapPath("~/pdf/") + "1.jpg");
```

but image not created in directory

Comment: I don't know what you are using there, but its not Ghostscript. It may be some kind of wrapper around Ghostscript (such as Ghostscript.NET, Ghost4J or GhostscriptSharp) but Ghostscript is etiher a command line program or a C-interface library or DLL. If you are using one of the latter, then you need to find out how to get the back-channel output (stout and stderr) and capture it. If there is a real problem Ghostscript will be trying to tell you about it using one of those channels. Other than that, I'd suggest you figure out which wrapper you are using and tag the quesiton with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dll file just works on x64 windows ...